# Renaming JSON properties if they contain a certain character without JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a bit of a unique problem. I'm currently trying to hook up a JSON dataSource to a kendo grid. Because of this, there can be no `#` anywhere in the JSON because it messes with kendo. So I have to take data like this:

```
[
    {"ID#": "1", "Prop1": "Val1#"},
    {"ID#": "2", "Prop2": "Val2"},
]
```

and escape the `#` so that Kendo can understand it:

```
[
    {"ID\#": "1", "Prop1": "Val1\#"},
    {"ID\#": "2", "Prop2": "Val2"},
]
```

The biggest problem with this is that the JSON could resemble just about anything: there could be any number/name of keys/values.

**My Attempts:**

I tried to escape the `#` like so: `var dataSource = JSON.parse(result.replace("#", "\\#"));` However, JSON.parse throws an error when I try this:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line 1 column 7 of the JSON data`

Then I tried to replace the `#` with `&num;`. It turns out Kendo can only support HTML entities in rows, not in column headers, without getting a template error. So I'm able to replace property values like this:

```
var dataSource = JSON.parse(result, function(key, value) {
       if(typeof value === "string") {
           return value.replace("#", "&num;");
       }
       else {
           return value;
       }
 });
```

This works for values! However, the keys could still contain `#` which will mess up my Kendo Grid. I tried to loop through each object and key/pair and replacing the key if it has a `#`, but for some reason when I call `Object.keys` the array that is returned is just 0s and 1s even though that's not what my data is named.

```
for (var object in dataSource) {
     for (var property in object) {
          if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                var keys = Object.keys(object);
                for(var key in keys) {
                     var oldName = key;
                     var newName = key.replace("#", "\#");
                     object[newName] = object[oldName];       
                     delete object[oldName];           
                 }   
           }
      }
 }
```

This portion above appears to have no effect. It doesn't even throw an error.

I also tried replacing the `#` with a string: `hashliteral`. Then, after the kendo grid was created, I tried using jQuery to replace all of the `hashliteral` with `#`.

```
var fixed = $("#grid").html().replace(/hashliteral/g, "#");
$("#grid").html(fixed);
```

This does work, but it breaks the kendo grid and all of the bindings. The grid functionality is a must, so I can't use this solution.

**Just to Recap**

I'm trying to remove/replace or escape all `#` in JSON data so that it functions correctly with my Kendo Grid.

- I can't use `JSON.stringify` and replace the `#` with `\\#` because then `JSON.parse` fails.
- I can't use `&num;` because Kendo headers cannot have special characters.
- I can't use jQuery to modify the `$("#grid").html()` because it breaks the grid bindings.
- The key can be anything. The value can also be anything.
- The JSON is NOT nested or complex.
- I cannot define the field/title on the KendoGrid columns because I have no idea what the field/title needs to be, the data is very dynamic.

I'm about ready to give up on this and just remove all `#` from the data. If anyone can think of some way to accomplish this: renaming the properties of an object so that all `#` are preceded by a `\`, it would be much appreciated. For the life of me I can't find a solution to this problem.

Comment: It seems that there is no problem at all on having `#` in a value. Check [this out](http://dojo.telerik.com/IJaKuH). Although I managed to escape the header's title with `#`, but it screws up the template. IMO it is a bug, it should take care of it anyways...

Comment: why exactly don't you loop through all properties and build a new object for further processing? did i miss something?

Comment: @lexith I haven't found a way to do this yet without knowing what the oldkeys/newkeys are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were already on the right track, but it's easier just to create a new list of objects:

```
var newObjects = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dataSource.length; i++ ) {
    var currentObject = dataSource[i];
    var newObject = {};

    for (var key in currentObject) {
        if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             var newKeyName = key.replace("#", "__HASHLITERAL__");
             var newValue = currentObject[key];
             if(typeof newValue === "string") {
                  newValue = newValue.replace("#", "__HASHLITERAL__");
             }
             newObject[newKeyName] = newValue;
        }
    }

    newObjects.push(newObject);
}

console.log(newObjects);
```

Hope it helps and i understood your problem correctly.

---

Edit: You can't have special chars like `\` as a key, so you have to actually use something unique like `___something___` which you could replace then with whatever later.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, you're right I was halfway there. After the grid was created I just did a jQuery find and replaced the `__HASHLITERAL__` with `#`. Works great now.

Comment: Happy to help :)